# Eclipse Indigo Apache HTTP server: problems publishing

Tags: apache, eclipse-indigo

I have an Apache 2.2 server that I am trying to use from within Indigo. I have a static web project and if I copy the project to htdocs it runs fine. However, when I try to publish it from within Indigo, I get the error message that the path cannot be found. Also, in the Servers view, the server is listed and shown as running, but when I open the context menu for this server, all the control options (stop, restart, restart in debug) are grayed out.

Additional info: 
httpd.conf DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
src dir/eclipse workspace: E:\workspace-html5\WebvilleTunes
i.e. is the problem maybe that my localhost and workspace are on different drives?
Also - also platform is Windows7/64-bit - and that's the version of indigo I installed.

Also, when I try to use the internal HTTP preview server, I get the error message:
Could not find required bundle org.mortbay.jetty.server. I see this has recently been registered as a bug, so I'm not very hopeful about getting around that one quite yet.

Can anyone help me get a server up and running for debugging a static web project (i.e. just javascript and html right now).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem as follows: de-installed and re-installed Apache 2.2 to E:\Apache2.2. It now works - i.e. can publish my pages from eclipse to Apache and pages work. I don't know if it is that the path is now on the same drive, or that it doesn't have any spaces or that the Apache 2.2 version is a slightly newer one (2.2.22) that maybe resolved some issues with Indigo, or maybe it was just the fact that I (re)installed Apache AFTER installing Indigo.

Anyhow, hope this helps anyone having similar problems.

Comment: BTW - as far as debugging HTML5/Javascript goes:
- it is true that you can't just drag and drop html that contains html5 features to your browser. You have to publish it to your web server and let the server serve the page.
- As far as debugging javascript goes, I'm now just using the Chrome  developer tools (which are part of the standard Chrome installation). The support for html/javascript debugging is fantastic.